# How can i enable HPACK in header compression using grpc in android

Tags: android, grpc

I'm implementing a service in a Android App to call a Grpc Service, everything's working well but the headers are no sending compressed, i'm using the example grpc android from the [official page](https://grpc.io/docs/tutorials/basic/android/) adding the two parameters in the payload (user and pass):

The output ngrep without compression

```
...........https..POST..authority.(/utdretailservice.UtdRetailService/Login.+!userAgent grpc-java-okhttp/1.22.1...application/grpc..te.trailers..grpc-accept-encoding.gzip..............

8095560000.
8095560000
###
```

The output ngrep with compression

```
..a........E.b??aR3P.???*?.&Ҥf?ql?b..?.?.A.q??\".?e....?_..u?b.&=LMedz..?ȴ?`+.+.@.te.M.5.?.@!@#@%$^%&^...............

8095560000.
8095560000
##
```

Answer (score 1):

Upstream Okhttp2 implementation does not fully implement HPACK compression, especially for the writer. Issue is filed at https://github.com/grpc/grpc-java/issues/5985.

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers)